# Start TightVncServer and provide password in a single command line

Tags: command-line, password, docker, prompt, tightvncserver

I am trying to add and start TightVncServer to a docker image.

When I want to start the service, `sudo tightvncserver`, I got prompted by a password.
Since I am generating an image, this needs to be answered without my input.

I tried: `echo "thePassword" | sudo tightvncserver` but I still get the prompt that requires not one but **two** entries:

> ```
> You will require a password to access your desktops.
>
> Password:
> Verify:
> ```

Do you know how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create your file

vim ./setpass.expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /usr/bin/tightvncpasswd
sleep 2
send "pass1234\r"
sleep 2
send "pass1234\r"
sleep 2
send "n\r"
expect of
```

chmox +x ./setpass.expect

Then run it